# Show rss feed xml for posts without content

Tags: wordpress

I am using RSS FEED's content from a wordpress site to show contents in a mobile app.
However, only posts that have content show in the feed. 
The posts that only have a title and no feed, do not show up.

How can I make possible for posts that don't even have a content show up in RSS2 ?

Answer (score 0):

when you are creating Rss feed u might be getting empty or null values...check for those and add something like NA or anything static that would be identifibale when u parse that Rss feed.

Comment: how would i do that ?

Comment: how are u creating Rss feed?

Comment: I am just calling the default wordpress method. http:// mysite.com/?feed=rss2&lang=EN&cat=3

Comment: go thrugh this...u will get idea to modify rss feed...http://digwp.com/2012/10/customizing-wordpress-feeds/#customize-wordpress